# What is program break? Where does it start from,0x00?

Tags: c, memory-management, brk

```
int brk(void *end_data_segment);
void *sbrk(intptr_t increment);
```

> Calling sbrk() with an increment  of 
>   0
>          can be used to find the current location of the program break.

What is program break? Where does it start from,0x00?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A program break is end of the process's data segment. AKA...

> the program break is the first
>   location after the end of the
>   uninitialized data segment

As to where it starts from, it's system dependent but probably not 0x00.

Comment: @cpuer: where ever the OS decides.

Comment: we should use unified terms to avoid misunderstanding. `data` segment is for initialized global and static variable. program break is the end of heap segment.

Answer (score 10):

Oversimplifying:

A process has several segments of memory:

- Code (text) segment, which contains the code to be executed.
- Data segment, which contains data the compiler knows about (globals and statics).
- Stack segment, which contains (drumroll...) the stack.

(Of course, nowadays it's much more complex. There is a rodata segment, a uninitialized data segment, mappings allocated via mmap, a vdso, ...)

One traditional way a program can request more memory in a Unix-like OS is to increment the size of the data segment, and use a memory allocator (i.e. `malloc()` implementation) to manage the resulting space. This is done via the `brk()` system call, which changes the point where the data segment "breaks"/ends.

Answer (score 3):

These days, [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) (and `brk`) are nearly obsolete system calls (and you can nearly forget about them and ignore the old [notion of break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk); focus on understanding [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)). Notice that the [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) `man` page says in its *NOTES* :

> **Avoid using `brk()` and `sbrk()`:** the [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) memory allocation package
>          is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

---

Most implementations of [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) (notably the one in [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) are rather using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to require memory - and increase their [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) - from the kernel (look at that  [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) wikipage, it has a nice picture). Some `malloc`-s use `sbrk` for small  allocations, `mmap` for large ones.

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out the system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) done by some given process or command. BTW you'll then find that `bash` and `ls` (and probably many other programs) don't make a single call to `sbrk`.

Explore the virtual address space of some process by using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Try `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps` and even `cat /proc/$$/smaps` and read a bit to understand the output.

Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) & [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).

And `sbrk` is not very thread friendly.

<sup>(my answer focuses on Linux)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Based on the following widely used diagram:

[image]

`program break`, which is also known as `brk` in many articles, points to the address of heap segment's end.

When you call `malloc`, it changes the address of `program break`.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that sbrk() is an obsolute system call and that we should use malloc(), but malloc(), according to her documentation, when allocating less memory than 128 KiB (32 pages) uses it. So we shouldn´t use sbrk() directly, but malloc() use it, if allocation is bigger than 128 KiB then malloc() uses mmap() that allocates private pages to the userspace.
Finally its a good idea to understand sbrk(), at least for understanding  the "Program Break" concept.

Comment: This is completely system and implementation dependent. There are various implementations of malloc.

Comment: Is this actually a comment to the answer by Basile Starynkevitch?